In my postman refresh_token I am getting error in my body though I am still getting the cookies
this is my user controller code  :-
const Users = require('../models/userModel');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const userCtr = {
    register : async(req, res) => {

       try  {
        const  { name , email , password}= req.body;
        const user =  await Users.findOne({email})
        if  ( user ) return res.status(400).json
            ({msg : "The email already exists."})
         if(password.length < 6)
            return res.status(400).json
          ({msg : "Password is at least 6 characters long."})
           
          // password encryption
          const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
          const newUser = new Users({
            name , email , password : passwordHash 

          })
          

          // save mongoDB 
            await newUser.save();
            // create jwt  to authenticate  
            const accesstoken = createAccessToken({id : newUser._id})
            const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken({id : newUser._id})
            res.cookie('refreshtoken' , refreshtoken , {
                httpOnly : true ,
                path : '/user/refresh_token'
           
            })

            res.json({accesstoken})


       }
       catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg : err.message})
       }
    } , 
     

    refreshtoken  : async ( req , res )=>{

      try {
        const rf_token = req.cookies.refreshtoken;

        if(!rf_token)return res.status(400).json({msg :" login or reguster"});
  
        jwt.verify(rf_token, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET,(err , user)=>{
          if(err)return res.status(400).json({msg : "login or register"});
          const accesstoken = createAccessToken({id : user.id})
        res.json({user , accesstoken})
        })
      }
      catch(err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg : err.message});
      }
     
    }
  }
const createAccessToken=(payload)=>{
  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET , {expiresIn : "1d"});

}
const createRefreshToken=(payload)=>{
  return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.REFRESH_SECRET, {expiresIn : "7d"});

}
module.exports = userCtr;

so   after registering the user and getting the access token  when I try  for the refresh token even though I get  the cookie I get a CANNOT POST  error in my body
for further references theese are my server file code and router codes respectively
server  :-
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require('dotenv').config();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());



const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: 'Hello World!' });
})
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
// routes  
app.use('/user' , require('./routes/userRoute'));
 



// connect mongo 
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL  ;
mongoose.connect(URI, {

    
}).then(() => {
console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log(err);
});

router  :-

const router = require('express').Router();
const userCtr = require('../controllers/userController');
router.post('/register', userCtr.register);
router.post('/refreshtoken', userCtr.refreshtoken);
module.exports = router;

I tried  to solve it for a long time but just couldn't find the error your help will be appreciated folks !

You have a strange implementation.
Is it convenient for you?
session.js:
const session = require('express-session');
class Session {
    #config = {
        secret: 'my_secret_key',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true
    };
    constructor() {}
    init() {
        return session(this.#config);
    }
    get(req) {
        return req.session;
    }
    set(req, key, value) {
        req.session[key] = value;
    }
}
module.exports = Session;

my_secret_key - this works out according to the principle:
const crypto = require('crypto'), 
secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');
console.log(secretKey);

db.js:
var mysql = require('mysql');
var interactive_timeout = 30;
var wait_timeout = 30;

module.exports.getConnection = function () {
    if ((module.exports.connection) && (module.exports.connection._socket) && (module.exports.connection._socket.readable) && (module.exports.connection._socket.writable)) {
        return module.exports.connection;
    }
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '***',
        database: '***'
    });
    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('SQL connect error: ' + err);
        }
    });
    module.exports.connection = connection;
    return module.exports.connection;
};
module.exports.getConnection();

request.js:
var crypto = require('crypto');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var db = require('./db');

function login(req, res, formData) {
    if (validateEmail(req.session.user) && parseInt(req.session.user_id) === req.session.user_id) {
        res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/success', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        return;
    }
    if (!formData.email || !formData.password || !validateEmail(formData.email)) {
        console.log('Wrong form data');
    } else {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email="' + formData.email + '" AND password="' + hash(formData.password) + '"', function (error, rows, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Database error on login');
                return;
            }
            if (rows.length === 0) {
                console.log('Bad auth');
            } else {
                req.session.user = rows[0].email;
                req.session.user_id = rows[0].id_user;
                res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/success', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            }
        });
    }
}

function success(req, res, formData) {
    if (!req.session.user_id || !validateEmail(req.session.user) || parseInt(req.session.user_id) !== req.session.user_id) {
        res.writeHead(302, {'Location': '/', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        return;
    }
    // your code .............
    console.log(req.session.user, req.session.user_id);
}

function validateEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^[-a-zA-Z0-9._+]+@[-a-zA-Z0-9._+]+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}

function validateToken(token) {
    var regex = /^[a-z0-9]{32}$/;
    return regex.test(token);
}

function hash(data) {
    var salt = 'your_salt';
    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(data + salt).digest('hex');
}

router.js:
var path = require('path'),
fs = require('fs'),
request = require("./request"),
querystring = require("querystring"),
handle = {
    '/': request.login
    '/login': request.login,
    '/success': request.success
};
function route(req, res, pathname, formData) {
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
        handle[pathname](req, res, querystring.parse(formData));
    }
}

server.js:
const express = require("express");
const session = require("./session");
const url = require("url");
const router = require("./router");
const log = console.log.bind(console);
function start() {
    const app = express();
    const sess = new session();
    app.use(sess.init());
    app.listen(3000);
    const urlencodedParser = express.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    });
    app.all(/.*?/, function (req, res) {
        let pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname,
        formData = '';
        req.setEncoding("utf8");
        req.on("data", function (formDataChunk) {
            formData += formDataChunk;
        });
        req.on("end", function () {
            router.route(req, res, pathname, formData);
        });
    });
}
exports.start = start;


Thanks but already solved the error the path written in user controller was not matching with my route and this was causing the problem..
